# Solving $(x - 2)(y - 3) = 6$ . Where $x,y$ are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In an exercise I have to solve $xy = 3x + 2y$, with $x$,$y$ integers.
So, I did this:

$xy = 3x + 2y \iff (x-2)(y-3) = 6$

And I found that
$x \in$ {$8, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, -1, -4$ } (as $x-2$ divide $6$)
and
 $y\in${$9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, -3$} (because $y-3$ divide $6$)

The problem is I don't know how to arrange all couples $(x,y)$ in the ensemble of solutions. Please help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: There is a finite amount of cases, thus, we make check them all, case by case.

Comment: $6=\pm 2 \times \pm 3 = \pm 3 \times \pm 2 = \pm 1 \times \pm 6 = \pm 6 \times \pm 1$ are the only possible cases

Comment: This is the ensemble of solutions: 
S = {(3; 9); (4; 6); (5; 5); (8; 4); (1; -3); (0; 0); (-1; 1); (-4; 2)}
But if we check case by case it would take a lot of time, I thought maybe there's some sort of technic or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Just notice which two integers can give a product of $6$ i.e., $2\times3, -2\times-3,1\times6,-1\times-6$ etc.

Now just equate you two terms with these two integers in ordered pairs (i.e, $(x-2)=2,(y-2)=3$ and $(x-2)=3,(y-2)=2$ are different ). You will have all the solutions.

Comment: Those learning number theory should be sure to understand how this depends crucially on both the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations.